# Ошибка drawable

Tags: java, android

Почему у меня выскакивает ошибка:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
'C:\Users\Asus-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe''
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

, когда в директории `Drawable` находятся 3 изображения, которые я хочу использовать, как фоны в `PageView`(свайп экранов). Если есть какое-то одно из них, то проект собирается нормально, если все вместе, то с ошибкой.

Comment: там выше должен быть лог ошибки

Comment: Ошибок нет. Это единственное, что выскакивает, прерывая сборку. Я уже все логи перерыл, причину не нашел

Comment: в любом случае, если без картинки все ок, то проблема с самой картинкой

Comment: Возможно, имя файла картинки очень длинное.

Comment: Имена файлов короткие.

Comment: Покажите названия картинок..Возможно, вы использовали там запрещённые символы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, `page1.png`, `page2.png`, `page3.png`

Comment: Возможно,  что в имени файла использовано ключевое слово Java или допущена ошибка, например, example.PNG. ?

Comment: @Артем, попробуйте их переименовать в к-л абракадабру. Возможно, дело в том, что в к-л зависимости есть картинки с такими же именами и из-за этого конфликт.

Comment: Также можно попробовать Clean проекта сделать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, о, переименовал - помогло. Спасибо!)

Comment: @Артем, написал в ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переименовать файлы как-нибудь иначе. Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29977893/3212712), возможно, дело в том, что в к-л зависимости есть картинки с такими же именами и из-за этого конфликт.